# Are DropBox files viewed on iOS devices taking up space on them?

Tags: mac, dropbox, ipad

When travelling I will need all of the "space" I can claim on my iPad. Am I correct in thinking "space" is not being taken up on the iPad by DB folders, unless I have made them favorites?

Comment: Note however that in order to view a file, it must reside on your iPad, albeit temporarily. We can assume that such files are stored by Dropbox.app in a temporary/Caches folder, but they still take up space, until they're deleted. When are they deleted? Perhaps when the app quits, but we're not sure. An inconvenient but safer way would be uninstalling/reinstalling Dropbox.app before traveling.

Comment: On my iPad, the Dropbox app is taking up a bunch of space ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/RioaT.png ), even though I have <5MB of files favorited. There's no way to force the app to clear the cache, either. Supposedly iOS 5+ clears caches when space gets low, but as @magma said, it's not clear when.

Answer (score 15):

Yes.  The files are cloud based until you favorite them.

Straight from DropBox:

> **How much can I store on my phone or tablet?**
>
> The Dropbox iPhone app can save as many files as your iPhone or iPod
> Touch can hold or Dropbox space allows. If you find yourself running
> out of space on your iPhone, removing files from your Favorites list
> will clear up space on your device. If you're running out of Dropbox
> space, you can delete files from your Dropbox, or you might want to
> consider upgrading to a bigger Dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

I think they cache them locally cause sometimes I'm able to view the images in my folders even while I'm offline but those files aren't on my Favorites.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted DropBox in relation to this. The files will only stay on the device itself in the sandbox area if they are favourited. If not, they will load into the memory and be dropped from memory once the application closes. Because they are cloud-based, they are "read" then "dropped" once no longer being "read". Kind of like a while loop in programming.

Source: DropBox technical support

Answer (score 1):

If marked as favourite then on iPad/iPod/iPhone

Looking at file means that it is temporarily downloaded  to view until application is closed, then it is removed.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

I have the Dropbox app on my iPhone and have closed and opened it multiple times, as well as resetting the phone, since getting a notice that my phone is nearly full, and Dropbox is taking up 3.9 GB of space without anything being selected as a favorite. Therefore it would appear that the files to take up space without being selected as favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a software called iFunBox http://www.i-funbox.com that allows you to "Manage App Data".

I noticed my DropBox app was taking 3.6 GB (99% data). Now I just used iFunBox to delete 3,6 GB of "uploads" from DropBox, and it shrunk again - works like a charm. And DropBox also correctly recovered - picked up to upload my camera folder at the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

The best and the easiest way to release the dropbox memory is that you unlink your cell phone and then linked again... I have like 1.9 Gb (the same as the photo and video files) I try this and inmidiatlly the memory was clean... the best part is when you linked again you not have to reload your files...

Answer (score -1):

Actually it saves everything on your harddrive. I just came to realize I only had 2GB of free space on my iPad. I downloaded iFunbox on my PC and with it I discovered that pretty much every file I've ever downloaded had a copy in a Cache folder under the Dropbox app directory. A couple of those files had even more copies because I had opened them multiple times. I deleted every file on my dropbox cache and recovered 12GB of free space on my 32GB ipad.

Comment: That is true for a PC or Mac or Linux but the question is about an iOS device

Comment: I think freddy meant the "harddrive" on the iPad, of which he used iFunBox to clear the Dropbox cache.

Answer (score -1):

Just freed up about 8gb on my iPhone! If you're running low on memory just delete Dropbox & then re-install it. Apparently stuff you either upload,download, or view still gets stuck or cached in the local Dropbox app on your iPhone. Note to Dropbox: Fix this! I thought I had a virus or something for the last 2 months! Everytime I uploaded a video to Dropbox I'd use up actual iPhone memory & not just my Dropbox "Cloud" memory.

Comment: How does this differ from other answers?